# Custom Module Not Showing Under Widgets

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.9

I am creating a custom module for "latest news" type of functionality. I have been following the docs on the Orchard website (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules-Part-1) and despite following this tutorial I cannot see the widget show up when I click on the "widgets" from the admin in order to assign it to a layer.

I am able to enable/disable the module and it *appears* to be working correctly on this page, but it doesn't show up on the Widgets section of the admin.

I have spent hours trying to find any answers, but haven't been able to so I'm reaching out here in hopes someone can offer some advice. How do I get my custom module to show up under Widgets? All I have done at this point is followed along with the tutorial they have on their website.

Comment: To let a content type show up under widgets, it must meet at least 3 conditions: 1. Attach CommonPart, 2. Attach WidgetPart, 3. Set Stereotype to 'Widget'

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `ContentType` that - as @devqon stated - has the `CommonPart` and `WidgetPart` attached, and it's stereotype is set to "Widget".
Have look at Orchard Doc's tutorial on [writing a widget](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-widget).